# Uncaught Error: Target container is not a DOM element. at Object.render (react-dom.development.js:26121) at index.html:19

Tags: javascript, html, reactjs, react-dom

1. 

> i have written script in the index.html. as i have seen many
> solutions people are telling that try to intialize the script.js at
> the end but for that i have wriiten the js at end of the index.html
> and im confuse its not working fine.as i have already tried to make
> a new .js file and write the code in it give the refrence at the end
> but it didnt worked out.
> '''
>
>
>
>
> Document
>
>
> React not rendered!!
>
> ```
>         <script>
>             const App = () => {
>                 return React.createElement("div", {}, 
>                 React.createElement("h1",{},'React is rendered'));
>             };
>             
>         ReactDOM.render(React.createElement(App), document.getElementById('root')); 
>             
>         </script>
>          
>          
>     </body>
>     </html>
>     '''
>     
>     
>     ######ReactDOM.render(React.createElement(App), document.getElementById('root'));##### this line of code is giving
> error as im new to react do kindly givea solution ty.
> ```

Comment: Is there an element with id: root in your html?

Comment: yes, 
<div id="ROOT">React not rendered!!</div>
    <script crossorigin src="https://unpkg.com/react@17/umd/react.development.js"></script>
    <script crossorigin src="https://unpkg.com/react-dom@17/umd/react-dom.development.js"></script>

Comment: `ROOT` is not `root`.... please correct

Comment: jezz. i'm so dumb ty for the help (GOD bless you)

Comment: Did the same thing with `Root` few years ago... ^^